# Enter key opens drawer menu (how to disable)

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, keyevent

I have a MainActivty in a barcode scanning APP, problem is that its not where im scanning my barcodes, and the barcode reader is always active. Its a hardware scanner and it always ends its sequence with a ENTER key press.

The Enter keypress is good for ending the scanned code, but in my MainActivity it gives focus to the drawer menu, and if i scan again it presses enter on the menu..

i tried this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    if(event.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Problem is that when i press ENTER

- First time it gives focus to the drawer menu
- Second time it opens the drawer menu
- 3rd time it gives me the TOAST as if its a ENTER click??

Any idea why this behavior is like this? and how to fix it.

EDIT:

After testing some more it seems like i have some errors as its not firing the KEY_DOWN event?

```
KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
                                                                            in com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2e60fd4 V.E..... R....... 0,0-800,1280}
                                                                            0: sent at 247739000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=247739, downTime=247637, deviceId=0,
```

Comment: Explain your query little more. Better if you can share the screenshot as well.

Comment: Return `true` if you've handled this event and don't want anybody else to handle it.

Comment: Main problem is that it does not registrer my enter event as an enter event. i think somehow the drawer is taking over the focus. Will try and take some Screen shots.